# Polynomial algorithm for HAMPATH transformed into an algorithm that solves the problem sequentially?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory

Let us assume (probably wrongly) that P=NP, meaning that we know a way to output a hampath if it exists.

A graph has $n$ vertexes.

Can the algorithm that solves the problem be modified in polynomial time to an algorithm that solves the problem sequentially?

By sequentially, I mean that the algorithm solves the problem by this way: an algorithm first finds whether a path with two edges that do not return to any of vertexes already reached exists, and then uses information gathered in finding aforementioned case to find whether a path with three edges that do not return to any of vertexes already reached exists and so on until $n$ vertexes.

Comment: Perhaps more appropriate to cs.stackexchange.

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Comment: It seems that you have posted several questions that are not research level using different names in a short period of time (it also seems that you have posted similar questions under other names on [cs.se]). Please don't do that. Read the [faq] and don't post questions on cstheory which are not in its scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a polynomial time oracle for solving an NP-hard problem, you can use it to solve any other problem in NP as well, including what you want in your "sequential algorithm": Given a graph and a path of length $i$, whether the given path can be completed to a Hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 0):

Given a polytime algorithm for HAMPATH, you can find a Hamiltonian path as follows. Start by guessing the initial and final vertices ($n(n-1)$ choices). We now try to uncover the path edge by edge. Given a path $p$, we need to determine whether it extends to a Hamiltonian path - and given such an oracle, we can find a Hamiltonian path by guessing the edges one at a time.

Given a path $p$ from $x$ to $y$, here is how to find out whether $p$ can be extended to a Hamiltonian path from $x$ to $z$ (recall we guessed the final vertex $z$ in advance). Remove all vertices in $p$ other than $y$ from the graph. Add a new vertex $a$ connected only to $y$, and a new vertex $b$ connected only to $z$. The new graph has a Hamiltonian path if and only if in the original graph, $p$ can be extended to a Hamiltonian path terminating at $z$.

Comment: If you think a question is off-topic please don't answer it on cstheory and wait till it is migrated to an appropriate site. Answering them on cstheory might encourage people to post more off-topic questions here.